# Post notice box?

Tags: support, questions

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), a box can be found below the question and above the "protected by" box that says the following:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and
>   context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is
>   right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations
>   may be removed.

It is shown whether or not I am logged in. How is this triggered?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's a moderator-added notice. Looks like it was left in response to the number of flags we were seeing on short, duplicated answers to that popular question.

I actually had forgotten we can do that. It's not used often.

Comment: Clearly, it needs an envelope to show there's a new message.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the *Class 1* Post Notices that moderators♦ can add to a post.

There are currently 105 posts with a visible Class 1 Post Notice: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/952820/postnotices-class-1

- "**Citation needed**" (Predefined, ID 1).
  It is currently visible on 15 posts:

  > Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.
- "**Current event**" (Predefined, ID 2). It is currently visible on 6 posts:

  > Post is related to a rapidly changing event.
- "**Insufficient explanation**" (Predefined, ID 3). It is currently visible on 84 posts:

  > We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

There are currently no (non-deleted) posts on Stack Overflow with a custom class 1 notice, despite the existence of the "Redditted" (Custom, ID 1000) Post Notice Type.